# How to rename a UEFI boot entry?

Tags: linux, boot, uefi, acer-aspire, firmware

I have some trouble with renaming the default UEFI boot manager entry on my acer laptop. When I bought the laptop there was a weird Linux distribution installed on it called "Linpus lite". I then installed Arch Linux distribution and a UEFI Shell. Then I tried to rename "Linpus lite" boot entry to "Shell" with no success.

First I tried "efibootmgr" linux program:

```
# efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,2001,2002,2003
Boot0001* Linpus lite   HD(1,GPT,d30143e0-3bd2-4090-b0a7-697dc65108ba,0x800,0x2fd41)/File(\EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi)RC
Boot0003* Unknown Device:   FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(c57ad6b7-0515-40a8-9d21-551652854e37)RC...0
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC

# efibootmgr -b 1 -B
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 2001,2002,2003
Boot0003* Unknown Device:
Boot2001* EFI USB Device
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM
Boot2003* EFI Network

# efibootmgr -c -b 1 -L "Shell" -l '\efi\boot\bootx64.efi'
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,2001,2002,2003
Boot0003* Unknown Device:
Boot2001* EFI USB Device
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM
Boot2003* EFI Network
Boot0001* Shell

# efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,2001,2002,2003
Boot0001* Shell HD(1,GPT,d30143e0-3bd2-4090-b0a7-697dc65108ba,0x800,0x2fd41)/File(\efi\boot\bootx64.efi)
Boot0003* Unknown Device:   FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(c57ad6b7-0515-40a8-9d21-551652854e37)RC...0
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC
```

I deleted the first entry and created a new one for the same filename but with different label. When I rebooted the laptop nothing has changed. There still was just a single entry for "Linpus lite".

Then I tried to do the same with "bcfg" uefi program from inside the uefi shell:

```
FS0:\> bcfg boot dump -v
Option: 00. Variable: Boot0001
  Desc    - Linpus lite
  DevPath - HD(1,GPT,D30143E0-3BD2-4090-B0A7-697DC65108BA,0x800,0x2FD41)/\EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi
  Optional- Y
  00000000: 52 43                                            *RC*
Option: 01. Variable: Boot2001
  Desc    - EFI USB Device
  DevPath -
  Optional- Y
  00000000: 52 43                                            *RC*
Option: 02. Variable: Boot2002
  Desc    - EFI DVD/CDROM
  DevPath -
  Optional- Y
  00000000: 52 43                                            *RC*
Option: 03. Variable: Boot2003
  Desc    - EFI Network
  DevPath -
  Optional- Y
  00000000: 52 43                                            *RC*

FS0:\> bcfg boot rm 0

FS0:\> bcfg boot add 0 \EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.efi "Shell"
Target = 0000.
bcfg: Add Boot0000 as 0

FS0:\> bcfg boot dump -v
Option: 00. Variable: Boot0000
  Desc    - Shell
  DevPath - PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x13,0x0)/Sata(0x0,0x0,0x0)/HD(1,GPT,D30143E0-3BD2-4090-B0A7-697DC65108BA,0x800,0x2FD41)/\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.efi
  Optional- N
Option: 01. Variable: Boot2001
  Desc    - EFI USB Device
  DevPath -
  Optional- Y
  00000000: 52 43                                            *RC*
Option: 02. Variable: Boot2002
  Desc    - EFI DVD/CDROM
  DevPath -
  Optional- Y
  00000000: 52 43                                            *RC*
Option: 03. Variable: Boot2003
  Desc    - EFI Network
  DevPath -
  Optional- Y
  00000000: 52 43                                            *RC*
```

Using this I managed to create a new entry called "Shell", but "Linpus lite" was still there. There were two entries pointing to the same executable. I tried this several times, but after every reboot that "Linpus lite" entry restores.

So the question is: how to remove that entry or rename it?

Additional info:
efibootmgr version is 13-1
bcfg (shell) version is 2.1
firmware version string is "Insyde Corp V1.20 11/13/2015"

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't wipe the drive completely, including the EFI partition, you also need to delete the folder in `/boot/efi/EFI` which is resembling the boot entry of the `Linpus` system.